# Switch off my graphics card when not in use

Tags: linux

My laptop is power hungry when it's idle because the GPU is always turned on even when it's virtually doing nothing. I've already turned the discrete GPU in BIOS. So it's not a discrete graphics card problem.

I want my linux OS to automatically switch off the graphics when the load is light and use the CPU for drawing. If I'm running Chrome, the GPU should turn on and start rendering (I can endure some stuttering at the beginning). If I'm running a word processor then the GPU should turn off. And all of this should be done seamlessly.

I'm using Ubuntu and with an Intel graphics card and only 1 moniter forever. If this is possible, how can I achieve it?

Comment: I do not quite understand the question. How do you expect to use Word if you have no display? _Intel Integrated Graphics_ is build _into_ the CPU itself, and has its own powersaving strategies. Do you simply mean turn off the LCD of the laptop?

Comment: No; What you want is not realistic nor is it possible